# Chrome browser Information returning odd

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to log what my user use the most when they visit. (At the moment I am just getting it to work. But soon I will be adding it to a file via ajax and PHP) but I am not so sure Chrome understands what I am asking it. It returns some weird info (Microsoft Edge too - but I expect that from microsoft) vs other browsers such as Firefox that return straight information. Here is my code as of now... (Only the browser info function)

```
(function() {
var browserInfo = "App Name: " + navigator.appName + " | " + "App Code Name: " + navigator.appCodeName + " | " + "App version: " + (navigator.appVersion || navigator.userAgent) + " | " + "Platform: " + navigator.platform + " | " + "Product: " + navigator.product + " | " + "Language: " + navigator.language + " | " + "Cookies enabled: " + navigator.cookieEnabled + " | ";
    alert(browserInfo);
    console.log(browserInfo);
})();
```

What chrome returns is

> App Name: Netscape | App Code Name: Mozilla | App version: 5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36 | Platform: Win32 | Product: Gecko | Language: en-US | Cookies enabled: true |

Vs Browsers like firefox

> App Name: Netscape | App Code Name: Mozilla | App version: 5.0
>   (Windows) | Platform: Win32 | Product: Gecko | Language: en-US |
>   Cookies enabled: true |

Why is chrome returning weird stuff? Not giving me a straight answer such as mozilla?

Comment: That is not weird stuff its part of their [User Agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) string, each browser is going to have a slightly different one. Also not all browser support all of those properties or return exactly the same format of information. For instance [appVersion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/appVersion) is deprecated and may return different information for the different browsers

Comment: Ah... so why is safari in the string?

Comment: There can be a few reasons, like both chrome and safari share the Webkit engine, [a similar question was asked over on webmasters stackexchange site](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20709/can-anyone-tell-me-why-does-chrome-tell-it-is-mozilla-and-safari-also)

Comment: So Safari supports webkit. Got to remember that.